# Collective service to build packages for Linux

Tags: linux, packaging

Is there a service that guides how to wrap your software for all flavors of Linux, and provides a build farm that cross-compiles them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Open Build Service](http://openbuildservice.org/) does just that: it allows you to build packages for all the main Linux distributions, on all the major architectures. You can build `.deb`, `.rpm` or `.pkg` packages, on RHEL, Fedora, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, Suse, OpenSuse, Arch Linux etc., on x86, ARM, PowerPC, MIPS...